# How to generate files outside the current package in Bazel

Tags: build, bazel

I am trying to write a bazel extension that reads some files and generates other files. I am using [ctx.actions.declare_file](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/lib/actions.html#declare_file) and [ctx.actions.declare_directory](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/lib/actions.html#declare_file) functions to declare files that I would like to generate, and then declare actions that generate these files. So far so good.

When I try to declare files/directories that are outside the current package though, Bazel complaints. For example, say that I have a source file `src = <source file foo/bar.proto>`, meanwhile the current rule is being executed when called by a rule `//baz/proto:some_target`. When I try declaring a generated file as follows

`generated_src = ctx.actions.declare_file(src.basename, sibling=src)`

Bazel complaints saying `Output artifact 'foo/bar.proto' not under package directory 'baz/proto' for target '//baz/proto:some_target'`. Looking at the documentation for `ctx.actions.declare_file`, this is expected.

My question is, is there some other way to declare a file that is not in the current package?

Comment: No I do not believe there is and honestly I do not think there should be. If you need to take an action on a file in a package and have the result associated with that package, so should the rule be used in that very same package. If you want to use the rule elsewhere, so should the result be associated with elsewhere.

Comment: @OndrejK. What about the dependencies of the target rule?

Comment: What do you mean with dependency on target rule? What a rule provides can be a dependency of you other rule. In that case you can depend on targets of other packages, but the result is "your own".